# Selenium webdriver cant find text field element

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Selenium Webdriver unable to find the element below. I have tried using name and xpath and none works. I am using ruby (but this doesnt matter) need a way to recognize the below page object

```
<input name="description" maxlength="128" value="" onmouseover="hoverField(this)"   onmouseout="jjj" onblur="blurField(this)" onfocus="focusField(this)" class="formInputFieldFilled" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, using XPath:

```
//input[@name='description']
```

I would hazard a guess it could well be in another IFrame, so double check this.

It could also be a problem of that the element is not visible on the page at the time, so take a look into WebDriverWait:

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, it was a stupid mistake I did. I had another page object before this one but that object was not available on the page. It was failing because of that. You saved me so much time ...thank you